# Virtual scroll is not working properly

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

The virtual scroll is not working as expected. It does not render properly.
When the page loads, first the list is displayed but when I start to scroll it disturbs the list and it does not render properly.

here is my span for better understanding.

after loading..

[image: After Loading screenshot]

after I scroll

[image: After I scroll the list screenshot]

here is my code

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]="members" approxItemHeight="50px">

  <ion-item *virtualItem="let member">
    <ion-avatar item-start>
      <ion-img [src]="member.profilepic" (cache)="true"></ion-img>
    </ion-avatar>
    {{ member.cname }}
  </ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

Comment: glad to know that nobody has the answer

Comment: did you fix it ?

Comment: yes @MissakBoyajian

Comment: what was the issue